# localhost:9200 error after installing and running elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have downloaded the zip file of elastic search on my windows, and extracted.But unable to run localhost:9200.

I tried running elasticsearch.bat file but getting the following error.
when I tried running localhost:9200 in the browser I'm getting page isn't working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx2PW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you downloaded the latest available version and ran it with all default settings and then typed http://localhost:9200, try using https://localhost:9200 instead. The current version of elasticsearch starts will Self-Signed SSL Certificate and if you try using `http` installed of `https` it just returns an empty response instead of issuing a redirect. Because it is a self-signed ceritificate it will not be trusted by your browser and you will get a scary looking error message about insecure connection. You need to do whatever it takes for your specific browser to convince it that you know what you are doing and let you through. Elasticsarch will then ask you for user name and password, which was autogenerated and printed out when you started elasticsearch for the first time. If you don't remember the password run

```
bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
```

and it will generate you a new password.

If this recommendation doesn't help, please post here the content of the logs/elasticsearch.log file that can be found in the installation directory.